# ¿Hay algo que haga que lo que cambie con un evento al volver a seleccionar cambie de vuelta a como estaba?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, eventos

Lo que hace esto es cuando se presiona sobre el link aparece "Logout" lo que quiero es que cuando se vuelva a presionar salga otra vez la palabra "Login", ¿Hay algun evento que haga javascript para esto? o con jquery? por favor que sea especificamente con algunos de esos dos.

la id login esta dentro de un link "a", y tiene como evento "onclick"

```
function Cambiar_Logout(){
    var logout= document.getElementById('login');
    logout.innerHTML="Logout";

    
}
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes simplemente preguntar por el estado actual del elemento. Si su contenido es `"Login"` lo cambias a `"Logout"` y si es `"Logout"` lo cambias por `"Login"`. Un simple `if` basta para lograr ese efecto. Te adjunto un ejemplo:

```js
function Cambiar_Logout(){
    var logout= document.getElementById('login');
    if(logout.innerHTML == "Login"){
       logout.innerHTML="Logout";
    } else{
      logout.innerHTML="Login";
    }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="login" onclick="Cambiar_Logout()">Login</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

suponiendo que esta es la funcion que llama el evento onClick, lo mas practico, aunque no lo mas elegante seria:

```
function Cambiar_Logout(){
    var logout= document.getElementById('login');
    if($logout.innerHTML == 'login'){
      $logout.innerHTML = 'logout';
     }else $logout.innerHTML = 'login'   
}
```

Comment: @Jaime Menéndez, me entretuve con otra cosa mientras escribia y quedo duplicado, jaja